# EntityFramework Code First Many to Many

Tags: entity

Today when I Create database from entityframe work code first I got a problem.First,I wanna create a many to many relationship between [Course] and [Institution].The code as below:

```
public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CourseIntroduce { get; set; }
    public int? IsMain { get; set; }
    public int IsShown { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Institution> Institutions { get; set; }
}
public class Institution
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime InputTime { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNum { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string WebSite { get; set; }        

    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

As my expected,the third schema [CourseInstitutions] with column [Course_Id] and column [Institution_Id] generated.But now I wanna to add a column [InstiIntroduce] in the schema [CourseInstitutions] in order to every institution has its own introduce for the course.So how can I change my code for this by using code first?Thanks in advance.